# Localhost can also receive packets from network adapter?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, localhost, tftp

I always thought that localhost is only using the loopback interface, and can only receive packets that were sent to the loopback interface.

Yet, on using tftpd64/tftp32 tool,  while it listens to 127.0.0.1 ,it can still accept requests from any other network adapter.

Can anyone please explain how can it be that localhost receives packets from other network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tftpd32/tftpd64 tool seems to give the wrong impression. Even though you select `127.0.0.1` from the dropdown list, it still listens on all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`), as seen in the output of `netstat -anbo`:

[image: screenshot]

I recon the dropdown list is just to allow you to see all the interfaces a machine has and not to select the interface the tool listens on.